# How to notify facebook people who have liked my post on facebook page to like my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Is there anyway on how to make people who have liked my post on facebook page to like my page by using graph api or something as going manually takes a lot of time to do that as facebook allows people who have liked your post to be invited to like your page.

Answer (score 2):

No, of course not. It would be called spam. If people want to like your Page, they will do it anyway. There is no need to remind them.

Comment: well u know some people feel liking the post is enough than liking page ...as we have an option now to invite them to like the page

Comment: they always have the option, but again: there is no need to remind them, and there is no way to do that, luckily.

Comment: sir i think there is a way as i got a like page request from a page who's post i had liked...i think u don't know about it..as a software enthusiastic person i wanted to know if it could be automated...

Comment: there is no api for it, it cannot be automated. it is a facebook feature.

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful for you: there is an extension that automatically invites people who liked your post - to like your page: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILgrsfB9bwc